# How to reorder the results of a for statement

Tags: python

```
monthly_kwargs = {}
for i in range(1, 13):
    gte = datetime(today.year, i, 1)
    mo = f'{gte:%b}'.lower()
    monthly_kwargs[mo] = Count('id', filter=Q(...))
    monthly_kwargs['SPECIAL_' + mo] = Count('id', filter=Q(...))
    monthly_kwargs['total'] = Count('id', filter=Q(...))
    monthly_kwargs['SPECIAL_total'] = Count('id', filter=Q(...))
```

The result of the code below is:

```
['jan', 'SPECIAL_jan', 'total', 'SPECIAL_total', 'feb', 'SPECIAL_feb', 'mar', 'SPECIAL_mar', 'apr', 'SPECIAL_apr', 'may', 'SPECIAL_may', 'jun', 'SPECIAL_jun', 'jul', 'SPECIAL_jul', 'aug', 'SPECIAL_aug', 'sep', 'SPECIAL_sep', 'oct', 'SPECIAL_oct', 'nov', 'SPECIAL_nov', 'dec', 'SPECIAL_dec']
```

But the result I want is something like this:

```
['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec', 'total', 'SPECIAL_jan', 'SPECIAL_feb', 'SPECIAL_mar', 'SPECIAL_apr', 'SPECIAL_may', 'SPECIAL_jun', 'SPECIAL_jul', 'SPECIAL_aug', 'SPECIAL_sep', 'SPECIAL_oct', 'SPECIAL_nov', 'SPECIAL_dec', 'SPECIAL_total']
```

Need to change the order of the for statements? I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it.

Comment: You will need to split up your `mo`, `'SPECIAL_' + mo`, etc as separate lists/maps and merge them after the for loop to maintain your desired grouping.

Comment: That's a dictionary.  You shouldn't really rely on the order of keys in a dictionary anyway.  And do you realize you're overwriting the `total` and `SPECIAL_total` values every time you go through the loop, thereby erasing the old value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Track the month names:

```
months = []
monthly_kwargs = {}
for i in range(12):
    gte = datetime(today.year, i+1, 1)
    mo = f'{gte:%b}'.lower()
    months.append( mo )
    monthly_kwargs[mo] = Count('id', filter=Q(...))
    monthly_kwargs['SPECIAL_' + mo] = Count('id', filter=Q(...))
    monthly_kwargs['total'] = Count('id', filter=Q(...))
    monthly_kwargs['SPECIAL_total'] = Count('id', filter=Q(...))

# Generate the month names:

months.append('total')
keys = months[:]
keys.extend( ['SPECIAL_'+mo for mo in months] )

# Print in order:

for mo in keys:
    print(mo, monthly_kwargs[mo])
```

Perhaps it would make more sense to track those in two separate dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks for providing a workaround. However, the result is not output as a list. The exact result I want is the list type ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', ' 'nov', 'dec', 'total', 'SPECIAL_jan', 'SPECIAL_feb', 'SPECIAL_mar', 'SPECIAL_apr', 'SPECIAL_may', 'SPECIAL_jun', 'SPECIAL_jul', 'SPECIAL_aug', 'SPECIAL_sep', , 'SPECIAL_nov', 'SPECIAL_dec', 'SPECIAL_total'] .

Comment: Because I want to use it like this in django: Student.objects.annotate(**monthly_kwargs) .values_list(*monthly_kwargs.keys())

Comment: Did you not see that's a one-line change to what I wrote?

Comment: When I load the monthly_kwargs keys in Django queryset, I want the following output to be displayed. ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', ' 'nov', 'dec', 'total', 'SPECIAL_jan', 'SPECIAL_feb', 'SPECIAL_mar', 'SPECIAL_apr', 'SPECIAL_may', 'SPECIAL_jun', 'SPECIAL_jul', 'SPECIAL_aug', 'SPECIAL_sep', 'SPECIAL_nov', 'SPECIAL_sep', 'SPECIAL_nov' SPECIAL_total']

Comment: Again, that's a very easy change to make, based on what I showed you.